# Porting Qt Applications from Mac OSX to Windows

Tags: windows, macos, qt, porting

I was wondering if there are any good tutorials for porting code from Mac OSX to Windows. I develop on Mac and my code works fine, but I would like to compile it to send the .exe file to friends so they can run my program on their Windows pcs.

I am using the Qt Framework 4.8 and coding in C++.

I have googled this and read around the net but I haven't found anything solid yet.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Well I don't know where else to ask this question. I have done research and found nothing really of use for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a tutorial. You can just compile your code on Windows after installing Qt. You can download the Qt installers from the [downloads](http://qt-project.org/downloads) page. You should choose Qt for VS or MinGW based on your c++ compiler. You can install either of those compilers.

Install Qt through the installer. It will install Qt libraries and QtCreator. Open your project .pro in QtCreator and compile.

Comment: I know that I can do this, although what I was looking for is a way to compile the code in the Mac OSX environment for Windows. Not compile the same code on the other OS.

Comment: So your question should be how to cross compile Qt application for Windows in Mac.

Comment: Yes, I did manage to find 1 link that had something. And I just figured it out from there.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many complexities to cross-compiling and deploying to another OS that I would say it's not worth trying.  If you don't have a Windows installation then you won't be able to test it, so you will spend many weeks sending new binaries to your friends which won't work (so you'll try something else, email it, that doesn't work...).  If you really want to get it working on Windows then you need to build on Windows.  If you are using Qt Creator and .pro files then you can do all your main development on your Mac, but then when you want to build for windows, check out your source on Windows and build it there.

Comment: I managed to find a package that compiled a .exe on my Mac and I just stored the executable on my Google Drive.

Comment: Just compiling an exe may not be enough: what about the runtime library linkage, manifest settings, copying the Qt dlls (and also its plugins)?

Comment: I didn't really think that far. But it seems to be working alright. The .exe ran without hassle on my friends pcs. I will have to think about that stuff in the future though. Thanks.